# Gherkin - how do you write an unambiguous test case in English?

Tags: java, automated-tests, gherkin

English could be ambiguous, and it seems to me there is an assumption in methodologies that employ Gherkin, that a anyone who speaks English to some degree, can write and understand the test cases, even before any code has been written.

So how does the methodology instruct you to work, given the following simple test scenario that needs automation:

In a Library application, to add a book to the library, the user clicks on Add, a Book Info dialog pops up and the user is expected to fill in the book title etc' and click OK.

Suppose the QA person writes the following:

```
Scenario: clicking the Add button
    Given a user who is already logged in to the application
    When the user clicks the Add button
    Then the Book Info dialog is displayed
```

Simple enough? Is this a good test?
i think i speak English but i don't understand it.

The fields in the dialog should be empty, perhaps some fields should have some default or initial value. Perhaps the tester expects the implementation of the "Then the Book Info dialog is displayed" to ensure all of that, but does the implementor know that? how is that communicated?

Perhaps the test should have been written as

```
Scenario: clicking the Add button
    Given a user who is already logged in to the application
    When the user clicks the Add button
    Then the Book Info dialog is displayed and all the fields are empty
```

It could take a couple of seconds between the Add click and the dialog showing. So the test may fail because the implementation checked too soon if the dialog is up, or didn't wait long enough for the dialog to show, and the test fails.

A person doing manual testing does not need to involve herself with that issue, unless it takes too long for the dialog to appear. So the above is exactly how this person would write the test (so the point here is that the tester needs to be smart enough to take this into consideration, or some developer needs to explain that, or they just fix it after the test fails).

Somehow, this simple action requires some more information... when is it communicated between the person writing the test and the one implementing the actions of the test?

Perhaps the test should have been written as

```
Scenario: clicking the Add button
    Given a user who is already logged in to the application
    When the user clicks the Add button
    Then the Book Info dialog is displayed within a couple of seconds  and all the fields are empty
```

or perhaps it should have been written as:

```
Scenario: clicking the Add button
    Given a user who is already logged in to the application
    When the user clicks the Add button
         And the user waits a couple of seconds
    Then the Book Info dialog is displayed and all the fields are empty
```

Is the person writing the test in English expected to

1. write all the expectations in the test action, e.g.
   "Then the Book Info dialog is displayed within a couple of seconds and all the fields are empty", or
2. write the short statement as in "the Book Info dialog is displayed" but then write an additional document that describes (in English) what is meant by this statement, and what are all the expectations?

Comment: Small formatting hint to make your future questions even better formatted: check up on how to do lists and syntax highlighting on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and check the current edit.

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, I'd argue for (closer to) the second.

If you pollute your scenarios with repetitive "noise" by adding assumptions, you've lost the concise, targeted ideal that BDD is aiming to achieve. It also becomes hard to know where to stop.

That said, if your story / scenario has specific requirements around these, or even if you expect it to have an impact on these, there's nothing to stop the addition of addition clauses such as `And all input fields are empty`.

Remember, if you are using an [Agile methodology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) like [Scrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28software_development%29), you'll have a separate *Definition of Done* which, although more business or process-like, can contain "global" requirements for accepting a story. These may include levels of test coverage, or performance requirements... arguably close enough to what you discuss here.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that your problem starts with your poorly written (and poorly conceived) Scenario description, and that mistake cascades into your scenario steps. "Clicking the add button" is not a Scenario, it is a step. And you even implicitly admit as much by making it your when step. :D

If I don't know what your user's goal is in this scenario, and what you are trying to prove to the user with this test, then I can't tell you how much specificity to include or not include in your steps.

And, without all the explanation and background you offer in the question, there's no way to derive any of it from your Scenario text.

So, here's a crack at a proper scenario description:

```
 Scenario: An authenticated user invokes the add book dialog
```

But there is *still* a problem with this scenario. Namely, it's still not a scenario. It's an action taken under certain conditions. That's all. I still don't know what the user is trying to accomplish.

```
Scenario: An authenticated user adds a new book to the library database
```

Now I know exactly who the user is, what the user wants to accomplish, and what we are promising to that user: that he will be able to add a new book to the library database.

And now I know what my test must prove: that the book I (as an authenticated user) tried to add, is actually added to the database. And now, I can construct a full scenario like so:

```
Scenario: An authenticated user adds a new book to the library via the add book dialog
    Given I am an authenticated user
    And I have a new book to add to the database
    When I add the new book via the add book dialog
    Then the book info is displayed in the book list
```

You can use the step definitions to build reusable code that "adds a new book via the add book dialog", or checks that "I am an authenticated user", or insures that the "book info is displayed". And in that step code, you can be as explicit as you like.

But if you're using Gherkin to test input field validation, by itself, then you're testing the wrong stuff. If you want to test that input fields are properly empty when a dialog is displayed, you should be writing javascript (or php, or python, or ruby) unit tests. If you want to test that input fields are properly validating, you should be writing unit tests. If you want to test that the dialog or light-box is behaving correctly, you should be writing functional tests. If you want to test that the data in those fields is being stored properly in the database, you should be writing functional integration tests.

But if you want to test that the promises you're making to users are being kept, then you should be writing Gherkin. Or rather, your Product Manager and your Test Automator should be writing it. If your Test Automator is trying to write unit tests with Gherkin, tell him he's doing it wrong. :D